# Cumulatative Subtraction in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I want to achieve cumulative Subtraction in pyspark.
I have dataset like this

| councs | coitm |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1110 |
| 100 | 1110 |
| 50 | 1110 |
| 30 | 1110 |
| 20 | 1110 |
| 2000 | 1210 |
| 10 | 1210 |
| 200 | 1210 |
| -100 | 1210 |
| 20 | 1210 |

My desirable result is this :-

| councs | coitm | _uncs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1110 | 1000 |
| 100 | 1110 | 900 |
| 50 | 1110 | 850 |
| 30 | 1110 | 820 |
| 20 | 1110 | 800 |
| 2000 | 1210 | 2000 |
| 10 | 1210 | 1990 |
| 200 | 1210 | 1790 |
| -100 | 1210 | 1890 |
| 20 | 1210 | 1870 |

For this I tried following code:-

```
df = _cost_srt.orderBy("coitm")
partition_by = Window().partitionBy("COITM").orderBy(F.desc("COCHDJ"))
df = df.withColumn("rnb", F.row_number().over(partition_by))

df = df.withColumn(
    "_UNCS", F.when(F.col("rnb") == 1, F.col("COUNCS")).otherwise(F.lit(None))
)


_output = df.withColumn(
    "_UNCS",
    F.when(
        F.col("rnb") > 1, F.lag(F.col("_UNCS")).over(partition_by) - F.col("COUNCS")
    ).otherwise(F.col("_UNCS")),
)
```

I achieve desirable output for rnb 1 and rnb 2 only, after that _uncs become null. How can I acheive my desirable code? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To achieve you scenario try below code:**

- Here I created column with negative values and the added the result bac to achieve desired output

```py
df = cost_srt.orderBy("coitm")
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("coitm").orderBy(F.desc("councs"))
df = df.withColumn("rnb", F.row_number().over(window_spec))
df.show()
df = df.withColumn("negatives", F.when(F.col("rnb") == 1, F.col("COUNCS")).otherwise(- df["COUNCS"]))
df.show()

result_df = df.withColumn("_UNCS", F.sum("negatives").over(window_spec))
result_df.show()
```

[image]